# google sheets turnning html to plain text

Tags: google-sheets

I've got some short html lists where I wont the tags to be removed.
Basiclly I've tried replace any thing in tags <> with nothing.
I've been using REGEXREPLACE and REGEXEXTRACT using the following regular expression: <.+>(.+)</.+> to try and get all that is between but it dosn't work.
the full formula is ​`=join("",REGEXEXTRACT(S74,REGEXREPLACE(S74,"<.+>[(.+)]{2,9}</.+>","($1)"))​)​`
​and the html looks like this:

PRODUCT INFO

- Honey wear me
- long sleeves
- Press closure
- Item care: Machine Washable

Comment: I thought that when you want to remove the tags like `<###>`, you can use `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"<.+?>","")`. But, in your situation, are you required to keep the format of the line break and list? I'm worried about this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it so if anyone comes accrose here's what I did (simpler than I thought)

> =REGEXREPLACE(S74,"(<.+>)","")

Hope I helped someone at some time :-)